# React Native + Enzyme + Jest: Mocked redux function call is not registered / is called zero times

Tags: react-native, mocking, jestjs, enzyme, jest-fetch-mock

I'm writing an app using React Native and Redux. I am designing a login form and want to test the components handle submit function. Within the `handleSubmit()` functions several actions should be dispatched to Redux. Let me give you the `handleSubmit()` functions code and the tests for it. First the function itself:

```
handleSubmit = (values, formikBag) => {
  formikBag.setSubmitting(true);
  const { loginSuccess, navigation, setHouses, setCitizens } = this.props;
  apiLoginUser(values.email, values.password)
    .then(data => {
      const camelizedJson = camelizeKeys(data.user);
      const normalizedData = Object.assign({}, normalize(camelizedJson, userSchema));
      loginSuccess(normalizedData);

      const tokenPromise = setToken(data.key);
      const housePromise = getHouseList();
      Promise.all([tokenPromise, housePromise])
        .then(values => {
          setHouses(values[1]);
          getCitizenList(values[1].result[0])
            .then(citizens => {
              setCitizens(citizens);
              formikBag.setSubmitting(false);
              navigation.navigate("HomeScreen");
            })
            .catch(err => {
              formikBag.setSubmitting(false);
              alert(err);
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
          formikBag.setSubmitting(false);
          alert(err);
        });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      alert(error);
      formikBag.setSubmitting(false);
    });
};
```

As you can see I'm also using normalizr to parse the data. The data of the `getHouseList()` and `getCitizenList()` functions are normalized within the respective functions.

Here are the tests:

```
const createTestProps = props => ({
  navigation: { navigate: jest.fn() },
  loginSuccess: jest.fn(),
  setHouses: jest.fn(),
  setCitizens: jest.fn(),
  ...props
});

...

describe("component methods", () => {
  let wrapper;
  let props;
  beforeEach(() => {
    props = createTestProps();
    wrapper = shallow(<LoginForm {...props} />);
    fetch.mockResponseOnce(JSON.stringify(userResponse));
    fetch.mockResponseOnce(JSON.stringify(housesResponse));
    fetch.mockResponseOnce(JSON.stringify(citizensResponse));
    wrapper
      .instance()
      .handleSubmit({ email: "abc", password: "def" }, { setSubmitting: jest.fn() });
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  it("should dispatch a loginSuccess() action", () => {
    expect(props.loginSuccess).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

In this test the values supplied to the `jest-fetch-mocks` (`userResponse`, `housesResponse` and `citizensResponse`) are constants. I now this test fails, because apparently the `loginSuccess()` which should dispatch a Redux action is never called (even though I supplied a `jest.fn()` in the `createProps()` function).

What am I doing wrong? Why is the `loginSuccess()` function never called?

**EDIT:** Upon request from Brian, here is the code for the api call:

```
export const apiLoginUser = (email, password) =>
  postRequestWithoutHeader(ROUTE_LOGIN, { email: email, password: password });

export const postRequestWithoutHeader = (fullUrlRoute, body) =>
  fetch(fullUrlRoute, {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(body),
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
  }).then(response =>
    response.json().then(json => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        return Promise.reject(json);
      }
      return json;
    })
  );
```

Comment: Are you sure all that code you posted to your question is relative to your problem? Making the question as short as possible would increase the motivation to answer to this question.

Comment: @Moyote honestly I'm quite unsure. The problem is, as I can't figure out where exactly the problem lies, I wanted to give as much information as I could. I don't know how to describe this problem in short precise sentences, and code speaks louder than a thousand words ;)

Comment: I understand. But if "code speaks louder than a thousand words", maybe it is getting too noisy now for possible helpers :)

Comment: @J.Hesters can you share the code for `apiLoginUser`?

Comment: @brian-lives-outdoors sure I editted in the question! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ISSUE**

The assertion on `props.loginSuccess()` happens before the code that calls it has run.

**DETAILS**

It is important to remember that JavaScript is single-threaded and works off of a message queue (see [Concurrency model and Event Loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop)).

It gets a message off of the queue, runs the associated function until the stack is empty, then returns to the queue to get the next message.

Asynchronous code in JavaScript works by adding messages to the queue.

In this case the calls to `then()` within `apiLoginUser()` are adding messages to the queue but between the end of `beforeEach()` and `it('should dispatch a loginSucces() action')` not all of them have had a chance to execute yet.

**SOLUTION**

The solution is to make sure the queued messages that eventually call `loginSuccess()` all have a chance to run before performing the assertion.

There are two possible approaches:

**Approach 1**

Have `handleSubmit()` return the promise created by `apiLoginUser()`, then return that promise at the end of `beforeEach()`.  Returning a `Promise` from `beforeEach()` will cause `Jest` [to wait for it to resolve before running the test](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api#beforeeachfn-timeout).

**Approach 2**

Waiting on the `Promise` is ideal, but if the code cannot be changed then it is possible to manually delay the assertion in the test by the required number of event loop cycles.  The cleanest way to do this is to make the test asynchronous and await a resolved `Promise` (or series of promises if more than one event loop cycle is needed):

```js
it('should dispatch a loginSuccess() action', async () => {

  // queue the rest of the test so any pending messages in the queue can run first
  await Promise.resolve();

  expect(props.loginSuccess).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

});
```

Comment: glad to help 